# what is the best practise of securing public api

Tags: node.js, api

I am developing 2 related websites which are public website and CMS.

Currently I have an api for registration which is POST /users 
It takes 3 fields which are username, password and permissions.

There are 3 permissions:
-Superadmin (having all access right)
-Editor
-Member (only having view access right)
Both of these users can login CMS.

In my public website, viewers can registration as Member using above api.
E.g. The parameters will be

```
{ username: 'ken', password: '12345678', permissions: 'member' }
```

What if some hackers simply open Postman and send api request with below parameters

```
{ username: 'hacker', password: '12345678', permissions: 'superadmin' }
```

In this situation, the hacker can create an account with "superadmin" permission and can access all of my secret Data in CMS.

What is the most secure way to handle this kind of api?

Comment: Don't send the permission type in the registration? A user is registered by default as only member and only admins can elevate him to admin or if he is the first user made don't do it through the API. This is a highly opinionated question